# How can I save the result of mailx command in unix to read mails to a text file?

Tags: shell-script, mailx

I want to save the unread mails to a text file in UNIX using a shell script. This shell script is executed frequently using crontab.
I have tried with the below code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

mailx > mytest.txt
if grep 'unread' mytest.txt
then echo "hello" 
else echo "bye"
fi
```

On executing the shell script directly from a server, I can see the saved text file with the result. But the execution stops after that.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If `mailx` detects an unread message, it goes into interactive mode and waits for you to send interactive commands for reading, saving, replying, etc.

You may redirect `/dev/null` into `mailx` to have it immediately exit:

```
if mailx </dev/null | grep -q 'unread'; then
    echo 'there is unread mail'
else
    echo 'there is no unread mail'
fi
```

The behaviour of this may depend on the exact implementation of `mailx` (it differs a bit between Unices).